# What is the smallest power $\alpha>0$ such that $(1+2s^2u^2)\le s^{\alpha}(1+2u^2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $s\in\mathbb{R}, s\ge 1$. I am trying to find the smallest power $\alpha>0$ such that
$$(1+2s^2u^2)\le s^{\alpha}(1+2u^2).$$
Surely, the above inequality is satisfied for $\alpha=2$. I would like to understand if $\alpha<2$ exists such that the inequality remains true.
If yes, how to find it?

I hope someone could help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The inequality is not satisfied for $\alpha=2$ if $s<1$. You need to solve for $\alpha$ in terms of $s, u$.

Comment: @CFD my fault, it has to be $s\ge 1$. I edited the question, I am sorry again.

Comment: $u$ is a function?

Comment: @zhw yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Divide through by $s^\alpha$ to get $$s^{-\alpha}+2s^{2-\alpha} u^2 \leqslant 1 + 2 u^2.$$ If $\alpha <2$ then sending $s \to \infty$ we get $\text{LHS} \to \infty$ but the $\text{RHS}$ stays finite.

Of course this is assuming $u$ doesn’t depend on $s$ which would be an entirely different story.